# Octopress has a pasword protected plugin?

Tags: octopress

There are no signs of questions in stackexchange regarding this one and I have done the reasearch. Having said that, I have to protect blog posts which are personal related but always wanted to let it stay online without me having to worry about access - the soultion is password protection as I used to do in Wordpress. e.g: `https://pwntoken.wordpress.com/2015/02/17/real-world-penetration-testing-a-gh0st-from-offensive-security/`

My question is something similar among those solutions which wordpress plugins provided are possible over the octopress framework? how do one accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben Balter has really nice way to go. See https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-auth

Comment: found this one helpful. Thanks.

Comment: So maybe you can approve my answer.